# How to get index of a Bitmap Image from bitmapdata(from an Array)?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am wondering if i have an Array that push content that is Bitmap, how do i get index of a specific image when clicked. I tried to use indexOf but no luck, my codes are below. 
Thanks for your time!

Code:

```
//First Part is where i add the URLRequest and add the image into contentHolder then onto Stage
function loadImage():void {
    for(var i:int = 5; i < somedata.length; i++){
        if(somedata[i]){
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.rentaid.info/rent/"+somedata[i]));
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,  onImageLoaded);

        }
    }
}


function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void {
    loadedArray.push(e.target.content as Bitmap);

    for(var i:int = 0; i < loadedArray.length; i++){
        var currentY1:int = 200;

        e.currentTarget.loader.content.height =200;
        e.currentTarget.loader.content.y += currentY1;
        currentY1 += e.currentTarget.loader.content.height +300;
        _contentHolder.mouseChildren = false;    // ignore children mouseEvents
        _contentHolder.mouseEnabled = true;      // enable mouse on the object - normally set to true by default
        _contentHolder.useHandCursor = true;     // add hand cursor on mouse over
        _contentHolder.buttonMode = true;

        _contentHolder.addChild(loadedArray[i]);
        addChild(_contentHolder);
        _contentHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscene);
    }
}

// then the part where i try to get the index
function gotoscene(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var index:Number;
    index = loadedArray.indexOf(e.target);
    trace(index);
}
```

Edit:

```
var viewport:Viewport = new Viewport();

    viewport.y = 0;

    viewport.addChild(_contentHolder);
```

Comment: Could you format your code? How is gotoscene called? Stab in the dark, change e.target to e.currentTarget.

Comment: Hi sorry i edited the code, i included how the gotoscene is called in the code, its a mouseEvent, when the content_Holder is clicked. I tried e.currentTarget, no luck, it displays the index as -1.

Comment: Bitmaps do not accept mouse clicks, so you're receiving a Sprite instead (or maybe even a Loader). So you should get the content, and query that vs your array.

Comment: A `Bitmap` is not a subclass of `InteractiveObject`, thus it does not receive events, thus it cannot appear as a value in `e.target`. This means there is a different object that's returned when querying target, namely `_contentHolder`. Apparently there is only one `_contentHolder` instance in your application, so you can't differ between clicked bitmaps while using `e.target`, you need to either have separate sprites to parse their children for index, or you need to calculate offset from `e.localX` and `e.localY` coordinates to determine which of the bitmaps is under the mouse cursor.

Comment: I tried putting the bitmap array into _contentHolder thru var _contentHolder: Sprite= new Sprite; but i am not sure how to add the bitmap to it so it does not replace the previous _contentHolder, because at the moment i do _contentHolder.addChild(loadedArray[i])  what it does, everytime it replace the last _contentHolder. I am not sure how to add each bitmap into a _contentHolder, then add all the _contentHolder into 1 viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question has very simple answer:

```
var image:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
var images:Array = new Array(image);

for (var i:uint = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    // images[i].bitmapData is the original image in your array
    // image.bitmapData is searched one
    if (images[i].bitmapData == image.bitmapData) {
        // found
    }
}
```

But your problem is bigger than this. I see you keep wandering around..

You should add listener to each child, not the content holder as one. I usually don't use Loaders, but get their Bitmaps and wrap them in Sprites or something, that I add into the scene. You should store either this Sprite or your Loader into that array, not the Bitmap. Then add listener to each of them (Sprite or Loader, not Bitmap) and get the target. Depending on what you've stored in the array, you can easily get it as:

```
function gotoscene(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var index:uint = loadedArray(indexOf(e.target));
}
```

But it's important to store one specific type that will actually be clickable. Don't think about the Bitmap - it's only a graphic representation, and doesn't do much in the code.

**EDIT:
Okay I'm adding the code you need but it's important to understand what you are doing and not just rely on someone else's answer :)

```
function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var bitmap:Bitmap = e.target.content as Bitmap; // get the Bitmap

    var image:Sprite = new Sprite();
    image.addChild(bitmap); // wrap it inside new Sprite

    // add listener to Sprite!
    image.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscene);

    // gets url of current image (http://website.com/images/image1.jpg)
    var url:String = e.target.loaderURL;

    // get only the number from that url by replacing or by some other way
    // this removes the first part and results in "1.jpg"
    var name:String = url.replace("http://website.com/images/image", "");
    // this removes the extension and results in number only - 1, 2, 3
    // it's important to change this depending on your naming convention
    name = name.replace(".jpg", "");
    image.name = "button" + name; // results in "button1", "button2", "button3"

    // store object, name, or whatever (not really needed in your case, but commonly used)
    loadedArray.push(image.name);

    image.x = counter * 100; // position so you can see them, at 100, 200, 300, etc.
    _contentHolder.addChild(image); // add newly created Sprite to content
}

function gotoscene(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var name:String = e.target.name;

    // strips down "button" from "button1", and only the number remains,
    // which is 1, 2, 3, etc. the number of the scene :)
    var scene:uint = name.replace("button", "");

    // you're the man now :)
}
```

Comment: Good code! My only concern is that there might be some performance issues from comparing bitmapData. If plausible for the project, a parallel/2D array may be in order to "index" the photos with strings. Then again, it totally might not be applicable here. Just an idea. Upvote all the same.

Comment: @JasonMc92 of course you are right :) LoaderInfo has loaderURL property, which can be taken when the loader completes (through event.target). This means that the Array can only store the urls of images and they can be searched later on. The problem is when we want to check on which image the user clicks. Of course, again there is a better option - to wrap Bitmap into Sprite and either save it in the Array, or save the instance name.. Anyways there are a lot of options to optimize, my code was just a sample :)

Comment: Hm, good workaround. Indeed, another one of those "there are at least 10 good ways to do this" type of thing.

Comment: My problem is even bigger than that, i realized that if i put each bitmap(loadedArray push content) into a sprite(_contentHolder) thru var _contentHolder: Sprite= new Sprite; inside the loop that adds the child. Then what i need to do next is add all the _contentHolder into a viewport, but at the moment when i add the _contentHolder to viewport, the second one replace the first, 3rd replace 2nd so on, and i am not sure how to have multiple _contentHolder that i can call an indexOf

Comment: Hi! Thanks, just before you edited the answer i tried what you said by wrapping Bitmap into Sprite then pushing it into an Array, i did public var newArray= new Array; then newArray.push(_contentHolder) and then i do index= newArray.indexOf(e.target);

Comment: Now i gotta figure out how to add all the _contentHolder into viewport without replacing the previous one. I think thats in your edit! THanks for the help!

Comment: Look in the code very carefully! The `image` object is the one with the bitmap inside, and content holder is **only one**, as it's container that holds all images inside. So you create one instance for each bitmap (`image` which is `Sprite`), and add this image to contentHolder. Then add contentHolder into viewport.

Comment: Hi, sorry i am keep bothering you, i managed to add the bitmap to image(Sprite) then add _contentHolder.addChild(image); everything works fine, but 1 thing, i can only click on the last image added, i tried clicking on the first,2nd image, they dont do anything, but the last image, traced index with no problem.

Comment: I wasnt able to do it because the extension from the URL isnt image1 or image2 etc. i am still figuring out how to do it, i can push the image into a new Array and get the index but then when i put addEventListener to image and put that inside the loop, it wasnt reading the index anymore